# Shorthand syntax gutters being ignored for span mixin

Tags: sass, susy-compass, susy

I've set global settings for susy:

```
$susy: (
    columns: 8,
    gutters: 1/4,
);
```

I want to override the gutters for a couple of span

```
.tile-left {
    @include span(1 of 2 1px);
}
.tile-right {
    @include span(1 at 2 of 2 1px);
}
```

Generated css

```
.tile-left {
  width: 44.44444%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 11.11111%;
}

.tile-right {
  width: 44.44444%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

I've also tried these and these don't seem to be working either

```
@include span(1 of 2 no-gutters);
```

&

```
@include span(1 of 2 (gutter-override: 1px));
```

Comment: "1px" doesnt work because argument must be a ratio, but I still wonder if theres a way to get the columns in % and the gutter in static px

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the "1px" argument didnt work because gutters can only be defined by a ratio value; [*Documentation*](http://susy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#gutters)

Furthermore, I've solved my issue of wanting fluid elements and a static gutter by
doing this:

```
.tile-left {
    @include span(1 of 2 (gutter-override: no-gutters, gutter-position: inside-static));
    border-right: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
.tile-right {
    @include span(1 of 2 (gutter-override: no-gutters, gutter-position: inside-static));
}
```

It looks like when you remove the gutters by passing "gutter-override: no-gutters" it calculates the width with gutters, but then removes the margins; By putting the gutters/margin inside by passing "gutter-position: inside-static" the with is calculated to span to 100% without gutters.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear in your post what you are trying to achieve. `@include span(1 of 2 no-gutters);` should remove the gutter output, but won't change the math. If your goal is to change the math so there are no gutters, `@include span(50% no-gutters);` might be the best option. Or `@include span(1 of 2 (gutters: 0));` should give you the same output.

UPDATE: even `@include span(1 of 2 0);` seems to work. The `0` is understood as a valid gutter ratio.

Comment: Yes I wanted to change the math, I wanted my span to be 50% with 1px. I guess I want my spans in percentages and my gutter to be static 1px with the math filling to 100%. If I use "gutter-override" to override the gutters with to 1px, the math doesn't calculate based on the new gutter width and doesn't add up to 100%.

Comment: CSS doesn't allow combining static `px` margins with fluid `%` columns to get `100%` — unless you use `calc()` (no need for Susy in that case). Your other option is to move your gutters to padding instead of margins (use `no-gutters` and add the `1px` padding manually).